# List not appending in the correct order

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement, append

In this code, I am trying to append the Gene description of the Gene IDs with the top 50 R-values. I am given two lists top50 and geneanno.

the list top50 looks like `[0.5218951111466706, 'AHY40589']`
and the list geneanno looks like `['AHY39293', 'Disulfide bond formation protein DsbB\n']`

my code below shows how I append the list but I just can't seem to append the correct gene description corresponding to the gene id.

```
    r_sorted = sorted(r_value)
unsorted = []
for s in r_sorted:
  if s not in unsorted:
    unsorted.append(s)
top50 = unsorted[::-1][:50]                           #top 50 with highest correlation
print(top50)

annotation = []
path = '/content/drive/abc_gene_anno.txt'
with open(path,'r') as f:
  geneanno = [l.split('\t') for l in f] #obtain gene ids
  for d in geneanno:
    for c in top50:
      if c[1] in d[0]:
        annotation.append(d[1][:-1])
print(d)
print(c)
print(annotation)
```

output is

```
[[0.9999999999999999, 'AHY39286'], [0.939173984187146, 'AHY39284']]
['AHY39293', 'Disulfide bond formation protein DsbB\n']
[0.5218951111466706, 'AHY40589']
['Cysteine-rich domain', 'Cysteine-rich domain', 'FdhD/NarQ family', 'Protein of unknown function (DUF979)']
```

Using the Gene ID (AHY39286) with the highest r value for example,
[image: this is the gene description]

However, my code prints this instead [image]

Comment: What is the desired output?

Comment: @BenWo desired output for annotation `['Pyridine nucleotide-disulphide oxidoreductase', 'Dihydroprymidine dehydrogenase domain II, 4Fe-4S cluster']` (gene description) which corresponds to  correct gene description in geneanno `[['AHY39286', 'Pyridine nucleotide-disulphide oxidoreductase'],[
'AHY39286', 'Dihydroprymidine dehydrogenase domain II, 4Fe-4S cluster']]` using the gene id with the highest r value as example

Comment: Could you not achieve the first part of your code more simply by using a `set` or more efficiently by using [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change order of your loops

```py
  for c in top50:
    for d in geneanno:
```

Currently, order of the `annotation` related on appearing key in the file

Comment: thank you! it worked! do you mind explaining the reason behind it? I don't get how changing the order effects the output

Comment: @SeahJiaHui you have unsorted list `geneanno`( for example first line of it contains `d[0] = 'AHY40589'` then you are walking throw `top50`, looking for this key with condition `if c[1] in d[0]:` (Note: d[0] will be the same for the iteration) and putting value d[1][:-1]. So it respect only order of the list from first loop

Comment: @SeahJiaHui
Try to run this code for understand it

  for d in geneanno:
    for c in top50:
       print("c[1]", c[1], "d[0]", d[0])

Then change loops order and run the code again

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your desired output correctly and you want annotations to be the text from `geneanno`ordered by the corresponding entry position in `top50` then you can use `insert`-

```
for d in geneanno:
    for i, c in enumerate(top50):
        if d[0] in c:
            annotations.insert(i, d[1][:-1])
```